# Backbone multiple collection fetch

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Is there a sexier way of doing the following:

```
scheduleSubjects.fetch({
    success: function(){
        subjectList.fetch({
            success: function(){
                assignments.fetch({
                    success: function(){
                        _this.render();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I want all the data to be retrieved before I start manipulating it.

Thanks.

Comment: Change scheduleSubjects to scheduleSexySubjects.  ;)

Comment: does nested call has dependency on parent calls?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [JQuery's deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), you can use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to trigger a callback when multiple async calls have completed:

```
$.when(scheduleSubjects.fetch(), subjectList.fetch(), assignments.fetch()).then(_this.render);
```

Note that this works because `JQuery.ajax`, and therefore also `Backbone.fetch`, returns a deferred object.

---

An alternative to `.then` is `.done`, which passes you the parameters of the original callbacks (which you don't need in the OP, but you may in some cases):

```
$.when(scheduleSubjects.fetch(), subjectList.fetch(), assignments.fetch())
    .done(function(scheduleSubjects, subjectList, assignments) {
        _this.render();
    })
);
```

Comment: This solution works like a charm. Made yours the best answer after all :)

Comment: Nice but how can we keep track of load progress with this solution ?

Answer (score 7):

```
var collections = [scheduleSubjects, subjectList, assignments];
var complete = _.invoke(collections, 'fetch');

$.when(null, complete).then(function(){
    _this.render();
});
```

use Promises and Underscore's `_.invoke()`!

Comment: Sexy :) Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Why is the first argument to `$.when()` `null`?

Answer (score 2):

You could either use promises:

```
scheduleSubjects.done(function () {
  subjectList.fetch();
});
subjectList.done(function () {
  assignments.fetch();
});
assignments.done(function () {
  _this.render();
});
scheduleSubjects.fetch();
```

or event listeners:

```
subjectList.listenToOnce(scheduleSubjects, 'sync', subjectList.fetch);
assignments.listenToOnce(subjectList, 'sync', assignments.fetch);
this.listenToOnce(assignments, 'sync', this.render);
scheduleSubjects.fetch();
```

You don't have to define these listeners inside a view. they could live in the application level.
The only thing the view cares about is to render once `assignments` are fetched

Answer (score 0):

The only other way I can think to do this is with backbone's `bind()` and `trigger()`.

With events you can achieve this functionality.. Not sure if there is a better way.  Once you have loaded your first collection you can trigger the loading of the second.  In theory the two collections shouldn't be coupled per your example.  The event based loading will decouple `subjectList` and `scheduleSubjects`.